# EOF sign in the middle of a textfile

Tags: c++, c, eof, getline

I'm trying to read files that contain CAN messages. Sometimes, there is 'rubbish' in between the messages, like here:

```
171250 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
171750 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
172250 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
172750 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
173250 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00›}¯!›}¯"›}¯#›}¯$›}¯%›}¯&›}¯'›}¯(›}¯)›}¯*›}¯+›}¯,›}¯-›}¯.›}¯/›}¯0›}¯1›}¯2›}¯3›}¯4›}¯5›}¯6›}¯7›}¯8›}¯9›}¯:›}¯;›}¯<›}¯=›}¯>›}¯?›}¯@›}¯A›}¯B›}¯C›}¯D›}¯E›}¯F›}¯G›}¯H›}¯I›}¯J›}¯K›}¯L›}¯M›}¯N›}¯O›}¯P›}¯Q›}¯R›}¯S›}¯T›}¯U›}¯V›}¯W›}¯X›}¯Y›}¯Z›}¯[›}¯\›}¯]›}¯^›}¯_›}¯`›}¯a›}¯b›}¯c›}¯d›}¯e›}¯f›}¯g›}¯h›}¯i›}¯j›}¯k›}¯l›}¯m›}¯n›}¯o›}¯p›}¯q›}¯r›}¯s›}¯t›}¯u›}¯v›}¯w›}¯x›}¯y›}¯z›}¯{›}¯|›}¯}›}¯~›}¯›}¯€›}¯›}¯‚›}¯ƒ›}¯„›}¯…›}¯†›}¯‡›}¯ˆ›}¯‰›}¯Š137550 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
137554 18ff9f1e da 92 64 64 47 89 16 f3
137958 18fed927 3b dd 5e 00 ff ff ff ff
137960 18fec1ee 2d 88 32 00 ff ff ff ff
154599 0cfe6cee ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
```

As long as the rubbish is just some signs, nothing is causing problems: I have made the software in that way that non-CAN messages are recognized and thes lines are then skipped. But the problem is that in that rubbish sometimes the EOF is present... and for example the function 'getline' cannot be forced to read beyond that EOF sign.

How can I proceed to read my files beyond the erroneous EOF?

Flip

Comment: Microsoft still treats the `0x1A` character (Ctrl-Z) as the EOF marker in textfiles, if present, as a relic from their use at the end of every text file in the old days. Open the file in binary mode. But then, you'll get the CR *and* the LF.

Comment: Detail: `EOF` is a negative value - often -1.  CAN data is best understood as unsigned.  It is code that is erroneously reading a byte of value 255 and comparing that equal to a -1.

Comment: "I have made the software in that way that non-CAN messages are recognized and thes lines are then skipped" --> need to post that code.

Comment: Hi all, I'm now reading my files in binary mode, and that works fine! Thanks for the help. Filp